# How can I prevent jQuery from triggering multiple times even with unbinders?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have both a PHP (demo.php) and JavaScript file (demo.js). I have a function that is supposed to create and object over a server, return it's key, use it to create its path, and then create a URL to it. However, only one URL can be active at a time so it is important that this only happens once. However, it is happening multiple times, and often sending me to a retired link. The last link created always works, but I want to prevent having to go looking for the links generated by this error.

My PHP (demo.php) looks very much like:

```
<div id="svg_graph">
    // just a graph (code is irrelevant)
</div>

 <div id="prompt">
      <a id="startup" class="button"> Create New Object </a>
 </div>
```

And my JS looks like:

```
 function funcA(){
      $("#svg_graph").mousedown(function(){
           $(this).mousemove(function(e){
                // irrelevant code
           });
      });

      $("#svg_graph").mouseup(function(){
           // $("a#startup").bind("click",function(){ // doesn't work either
           $("a#startup").click(function(){
                // Supposed to prevent multiple clicks, but doesn't
                $("a#startup").unbind("click");
                funcB();
           });
           $(this).unbind("mousemove");
      });
 }

 // This function is being called more than once but I don't know why
 function funcB(data){
      var obj = createObj(data);
      var url = "some predefined url" + obj.key;
      window.location.replace(url);
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

These days, you should be using `.off()`, though `.unbind()` should stil work.

If unbinding is indeed the issue, then you might have better luck with :

```
$("#svg_graph").off('mouseup').on('mouseup', function() {
    $("a#startup").off('click').on('click', function() {
        funcB();
        return false; // probably
    });
});
```